# Fluentd copy output plugin to https server

Tags: fluentd, fluent-design

I am trying to copy event to https server. I have a list of ports and IPs and I need that FluentD will try sending the event to the first IP it succeeded in sending and only that IP.

1. what should be the type inside  when sending copy to https server

   ```
    <match analytics>
      type copy
      <store>
        type **https**?
   ```
2. how should I add this logic that sends the data only to one IP from the list

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [http](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/http) output plugin with TLS configuration. Also, it's `@type`, not just `type`.

Comment: For the 2nd question, what do you mean by the list of IPs? You can configure only one IP that you need.